# Can I use Struts2 without Spring IoC?

Tags: java, spring, struts2

Can I use Struts2 without Spring IoC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Yes

Spring IOC is just a pluggable object dependency container, which manages objects for you. It is optional.

Comment: +1. Thanks, But I find quote in Starting Struts2 '...And finally, dependency injection is now a first class citizen – provided via the Spring Framework...' by Ian Roughley, How I should understand it?

Comment: mostly with good designed project Spring[*IOC*] is used at service layer with struts. you can follow tutorial [here](http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-tutorial/struts-2-framework-tutorial-1.html)  & [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/struts2-tutorial-part-17?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+javalobby/frontpage+(Javalobby+/+Java+Zone))

Comment: IoC is a good thing, it is generally best to start with the struts2 documentation (using the struts2-spring-plugin) http://struts.apache.org/2.0.8/docs/spring-plugin.html

Comment: @Quat Yes, Spring IOC is very good thing, but as beginner I would recommend OP to quick start plain struts and then he will automatically switch with Spring :)

Answer (score 4):

Spring is only one option. You can work with others like Google Guice or without IOC.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, even when you can integrate both on your project, it is **not** required.

Answer (score 2):

Struts2 was designed with dependency injection in mind and adheres to the principles pretty well (the underlying XWork framework uses an early version of Guice). You can step up to Guice or Spring later using the appropriate plug-in.

Answer (score -1):

Basically both are independent. You can definitely use Struts 2 without Spring IOC.